# How to upload a file to database using the endpoint provided in webAPI C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have an end point("uploadmyfile") to which I need to upload a file to the database using the webapi service. I am not sure how to upload a file.

I did uploading an object using PostAsync as below.

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings {ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()};
var data = JsonCOnvert.SerializeObject(objectData, settings);
HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
HttpResponseMessage tResp = await Hclient.PostAsync("uploadmyfile", httpContent);
```

If I am aware of what content is in the file, I can create a class of same structure and can serialize the content to that particular type. As I don't know what content resides in the file, I cannot create an object of that content type and serialize it.

I am very new to the webapi stuff. Kindly excuse me if pointed out anything wrong.

It would be great if anyone can help me out to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Create a binary column in the database, or use byte[] in Entity Framework, and just save the file as byte[]. So you don't have to know anything about the file.